# Port Forwarding for AirPlay on OS X Server

Tags: network, osx-server, airplay

I have set up an old Mac Mini I have lying around, as a Server, and it is performing magnificently.

I have some AirPlay enabled speakers that I am trying to connect to my MBP. Unfortunately the MBP does not see them.

I logged in remotely to the Mac Mini server and launched iTunes - the AirPlay speakers are present there. I am therefore assuming that there's some kind of a port forwarding issue for the AirPlay service.

- I have found [this article listing the ports that are used by AirPlay devices](http://bowersandwilkins.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/55/~/firewall-ports-utilised-by-airplay). I am now trying to forward them from my Mac Mini to my MBP.
- I found [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH9012?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), listing a procedure for portforwading but it's outdated and I am not sure wether it still valid for a OS X 10.9 server.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what the procedure for setting up port forwarding on a  Mac Server is?

Comment: Are all 3 items (the Mini server, the MBPro, and the speakers) on the same subnet? Or - are you trying to connect the MBPro remotely via AirPlay to the speakers?

Comment: Well since the Mini server hands out the IP addresses I believe all of them are on the same subnet.
And yes - I am trying to remotely connect the MBP to the speakers via AirPlay.

Comment: @Scot I take that back. After double checking it turns out that the Mac Mini has an IP address of 192.168.1.90 (255.255.255.0) and the MBP is at 192.168.2.4 which AFAIK are not on the same subnet.
 
**Progress update:** Both the Mac Mini and the MBP are now in the same subnet. The AirPlay problem still persists

Comment: OK - good. So - all the IPs (MBPro, Mini, and Speakers) are now on the same LAN, and the same subnet. You seem to be using the Mini Server as your router. Do you have any other routers on your network? If so, this may be causing this issue.

If not, you shouldn't need to deal with port forwarding - this is mainly to allow devices on opposite sides of a firewall, or NAT to access each other. Can the Mac Mini and MBPro see each other (within the Finder, under the Shared devices tab)?

Comment: @Scot - no. I can see all windows PCs, but not my MBP. Weird. Both of my firewalls are off. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that the MBPro is on the same network as everything else? Do you have multiple routers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11593/discussion-between-scot-and-atanas-bozhkov)